# Downloading sectorwise classification map and data of India

Tags: geospatial, india, map

Can you suggest where I can download the exact data and map of the sectorwise (industrial, commercial, residential, agricultural, and forest) land use patterns of India?

Is this available on the Bhuvan (Indian Geo-spatial data portal) or Survey of India websites.

Or any other sources?

Comment: My https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/20398/30273 under "Land cover/use data (rural vs urban for example):" may or may not be helpful