# augment/enrich latitude longitude data

Tags: demographics, geocoding, python, population, restaurant

I am looking for ways to augment/enrich latitude longitude data, to obtain for example information like this (for the EU/Europe and the UK):

- rural/urban area
- distance to lake/sea
- distance to nearest town/village
- number of restaurants nearby

I tried some basic Python code to use :

```
import geocoder

g = geocoder.osm([45,-75], method='reverse')
print(g)
```

This returns:

```
<[OK] Osm - Reverse [Ault Drive, Ingleside, South Stormont, Stormont, Dundas and Glengarry Counties, Eastern Ontario, Ontario, K0C 1M0, Canada]>
```

so not useful for my use case. What else could I explore, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually working on a project like this (feel free to contact me directly for more details) and here are some sources I know above and beyond OpenStreetMap:

- Coastal distance: https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/distfromcoast/ (caveat: treats inland seas, such as the Caspian Sea, as land)
- More accurate coastal distance (but you have to calculate it yourself, I used GRASS GIS): http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/pwessel/gshhg/
- Land cover/use data (rural vs urban for example):

  - https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/news/NasaNews/ReleaseImages/LCC/
  - https://www.gsi.go.jp/kankyochiri/gm_global_e.html under "Land Cover (GLCNMO)
  - https://www.esa-landcover-cci.org/?q=node/158
- Elevation data: https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/
- Animal habitat data: https://www.iucnredlist.org/resources/spatial-data-download (may require free login to actually download linked data)
- Climate data: http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/
- Population count and density:

  - https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/collection/gpw-v4
  - https://data.worldpop.org/GIS/Population/Global_2000_2020/ (see https://data.worldpop.org/ or https://data.humdata.org/ for more general information)
- Ethnicity data: https://icr.ethz.ch/data/epr/#geoepr
- Solar energy availability: https://energydata.info/dataset/world-photovoltaic-power-potential-pvout-gis-data-global-solar-atlas
- https://www.naturalearthdata.com/ has lots of free data of various types though it's at lower resolution that some of the more specific sites above
- For completeness, there are many sources of weather data at [Sources of weather data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155) but, if you're looking for general properties of a given latitude/longitude, you're almost certainly more interested in climate, not weather
- I do have other data, but it's fairly obscure and probably uninteresting.